# Prevent my phone from showing messages in the wrong order if I reply quickly?

Tags: sms, htc-desire-s

When I access the Messages app that came with my phone and select a person I am presented with all the SMS messages my phone has stored between me and that person, in chronological order.

However, I get a message from someone and reply quickly, my message is permanently positioned *above* the message it is a reply to, not below it, even though it was sent at a later time.

What is causing this frustrating behaviour, and what can I do to ensure correct sorting order?

Comment: Pain in the neck this one. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *seems* to be related to the local time on my phone, which I suspect was slow compared to the network. So, while the incoming messages where arriving listed as the "correct" time (on the network), I was then replying "before" them as far as my local clock was concerned and thus when the phone sorted on time their positions were swapped.

So, I've manually adjusted my clock forward a minute, and seem to have avoided the problem since.

<sub>Speaking to a friend knowledgeable in these things, O2 (my provider) *apparently* do not provide phones with network-updated time, I don't know if this is true or not, but it would explain how a difference could appear in the manner described.</sub>

Comment: I'm not 100% convinced yet that this is correct, but I'll accept this when I am - so will give it a while longer, maybe do some purposeful tests, to see if I get any message inversions.